# Casting java.lang.Object to custom object raises ClassCastException

Tags: java, casting

So, this is an oddball issue. I work in an embedded environment and I'm trying to send a message (object) from one application to another application. API-standard objects such as java.lang.String will work just fine, but when I try to send an object fo a custom class, a ClassCastException is raised.

Here's the setup: I have a sender application and a receiver application. In the sender application, I instantiate an UserUAI object (a custom class included in a library I wrote), cast it to Object and send it to the receiving application using the supporting class ComManager included in the environment API. But that's ok, it works fine, and like I said before, if I use API-compliant objects, I have no problem whatsoever.

Sending end:

```
UserUAI userUAI = new userUAI(/*param list*/);
ComManager.getInstance().sendMessage(targetAppPID, userUAI);
//method signature: void sendMessage(String targetAppPID, Object message)
```

Receiving end:

```
Object received = (UserUAI)receiver.getReceivedMessage(); 
UserUAI userUAI = (UserUAI)received; //raises exception
//method signature: Object getReceivedMessage();
```

I checked, double checked and triple checked, the received object is of UserUAI type at runtime.

Also, I'm posting the results of a suggestion that Paŭlo Ebermann gave me:

**received.getClass()** -> class nddigital.support.ricoh.UserUAI

**UserUAI.class** -> class nddigital.support.ricoh.UserUAI

**received.getClass().getClassLoader()** -> 
jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.osgi.service.multiXletManager.XletClassloader@2d4f9e

**UserUAI.class.getClassLoader** -> 
jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.osgi.service.multiXletManager.XletClassloader@4464ab

**UserUAC.class == received.getClass()** -> false

**UserUAC.class.getClassLoader() == received.getClass().getClassLoader()** -> false

I hope someone out there can lend me a hand. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: jobList.getJobList returns an Object array, I thought that could be some implicit casting going on there, but there isn't

Comment: You can use a debugger to determine the runtime type of the `receiver.getReceivedMessage()`. It is likely not what you think it is. Or at the very least `System.out.println(obj.getClass())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To qoute the [Java Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.3.4) part of §4.3.4

> Two reference types are the same run-time type if:
>
> They are both class or both interface types, **are defined by the same class loader**, 
>   and have the same binary name (§13.1), in which case they are sometimes said to be the 
>   same run-time class or the same run-time interface.
>
> They are both array types, and their component types are the same run-time type(§10).

And in [Casting Conversions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.5) it says.

> If T is a class type, then R must be either the **same class (§4.3.4)** as T or 
>   a subclass of T, or a run-time exception is thrown.

So, since the same classes have been defined by different class loaders, its instances can not be cast to other.

Comment: Thanks, that will do. Not ideal, but I already expected to have hit a technological boundary.

Comment: It just ocurred to me... What if I convert the object into a byte array before sending, send the message, convert it from byte array to object (I actually don't know how to do it in Java, only C#) and then cast it to UserUAI?

Comment: Thanks for posting that, it gave me the idea I needed to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

From the exception, clearly the object returned by receiver.getReceivedMessage() is not of type UserUAI. If this method has to return Object and you cannot change it to return a specific type so you prevent a blind type cast from object, then atleast you could do

```
Object received = receiver.getReceivedMessage();
if(received instanceof UserUAI)
{

   UserUAI userUAI = (UserUAI) received;
}
```

to prevent the error.

Comment: This is how it goes: I have a SenderGUI class where I instantiate a regular UserUAI object. I pass it to a SenderControl class, so to speak casting it to Object type, but watching the code in real time reveals it still retains its UserUAI type properties. Then I send it to the receiving end as method parameter of type object... let's call it "sendMessage", for simplification's sake. In the receiving end, the return type of getReceivedMessage is also object, but watching the variable in the debugger, it still retains its userUAI properties. Except that if(received instance of UserUAI) is false!

Comment: so what is the runtime type of the received object? you can check get that in debugger.

Comment: OMG... The display window (using received.getClass()) returns UserUAI

Comment: also make sure you check the fully qualified name. they could be two different UserUAIs from different packages.

Comment: They're both from the nddigital.support.ricoh package, a library I built myself. The only unusual thing about my scenario is that, like I said before, I'm casting a UserUAI to object, sending this object to another application using the ComManager library (exclusive to Ricoh Embedded development) and then trying to cast it back to UserUAI. I could send the UserUAI-typed object itself, but I'd rather send this data in a more of a raw state.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments to the other answers, it looks like you have classloader issues.

Try this:

```
Object received = receiver.getReceivedMessage();

System.out.println(received.getClass());
System.out.println(UserUAI.class);

System.out.println(received.getClass.getClassLoader());
System.out.println(UserUAI.class.getClassLoader());

System.out.println(UserUAI.class == received.class);
System.out.println(UserUAI.class.getClassLoader() == received.getClass.getClassLoader());
```

Even if the first two outputs look same, they are different classes if loaded by different classloaders.

To solve this, we will need more context about how you are using this.

Comment: Hold on there, god damn embedded environment is causing me trouble. I'll post the results as soon as I can

Comment: So, there we go
class nddigital.support.ricoh.UserUAC
class nddigital.support.ricoh.UserUAC

jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.osgi.service.multiXletManager.XletClassloader@2d4f9

Comment: So, there we go
received.getClass() -> class nddigital.support.ricoh.UserUAI, 
UserUAI.class -> class nddigital.support.ricoh.UserUAI, 

received.getClass().getClassLoader() -> jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.osgi.service.multiXletManager.XletClassloader@2d4f9e, 

UserUAI.class.getClassLoader -> jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.osgi.service.multiXletManager.XletClassloader@4464ab, 

UserUAC.class == received.getClass() -> false, 
UserUAC.class.getClassLoader() == received.getClass().getClassLoader() -> false. Sorry about the multiple posts. I don't like it one bit...

Comment: Okay, so we see here that your classes are loaded by different instances of the same ClassLoader class. As this is an OSGI environment (or looks like this), you should make sure that the UserAI class is exported by one of your bundles, and imported by the other one (from this first one), or imported by both from a third bundle, instead of delivering it with both bundles.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the object returned by  `receiver.getReceivedMessage()` isn't a `UserUAI`. You could set a breakpoint and find out exactly what it is returning.

A better approach would be to use generics if at all possible. Can't really tell from the bit of code you've shown.

Comment: Generics is not an option as I'm stuck with Java 1.4.2

Comment: @S.O. Been there. I feel your pain.

Comment: Actually it would be quite complicated to explain what's going on since this snippet is from an application receiving an object from another application (getReceivedMessage() is the receiving end), both running within an embedded environment. The sending end instantiates the object sent as UserUAI, but I cast it to Object before sending it. Unfortunatelly casting it back upon arrival isn't working.

Comment: @S.O. Really, your best bet is to set a breakpoint and see what `getReceivedMessage()` actually returns.

Comment: It returns UserUAI. Same package and everything.

Comment: @S.O. Could you please update your original question with the additional details you've gathered? It's much easier to have that all in one place instead of inserted into comments on each answer. Also, you can format it better. To further the troubleshooting: could the sender and receiver have different versions of the UserUAI class?

Comment: It is possible, although I take a lot of care when I'm exporting everything, so that the libraries and references in both applications (sender and receiver) are the same. I'll reright the OP, hold on

Answer (score 0):

As said above, the object being returned is not of the right type.  Here's an easy way to figure out what type of object is actually being returned.  If you get a NullPointerException, then the object returned was null

```
private Object o = receiver.getReceivedMessage();
System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
```

Comment: True, but that would take longer than 2 lines to show the intent.  Its meant as an example, not as production ready

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in front of me the whole time. I made the UserUAI class serializable and sent it as a byte array. In the receiving end, I deserialize it and cast the resulting object to UserUAI and it works just fine.

Ishtar, thanks for your post, it was the specification text that gave me the idea.